# Avoid duplicates in a set

Tags: groovy

I have an array of objects which is defined as below:

```
def list = [{'name':'test','grade':1,'num':1},{'name':'test1','grade':2,'num':2},{'name':'test','grade':1,'num':1}]
```

I am trying to avoid duplicate of num values so i tried the below way:

```
//Set<String> studentArray = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(studentList.num));

HashSet <String> studentInfo = new HashSet <String>();

studentInfo.addAll(list.num)

println("Information:"+studentInfo);
```

Now I can see distinct values but in the console, I see the value is appending with an array like [1]. How to see only the value?

Comment: `*Set* studen*Array*` - names have power ;)

Comment: What do you mean by _"the value is appending with an array like [1]"_ ? The code you have shown produces the output like `Information:[1, 2]` which is exactly what you can expect from it. It prints a set of values. None of the value is nested in an array or list.

Answer (score 3):

`HashSet` does not allow to duplicate values. The code you have constructed creates a set of a single list of elements 1, 2 and 1. If you print `studentArray` to the console you will see something like this:

```
[[1, 2, 1]]
```

And this is correct because the type of the constructed structure is `Set<List<Integer>>`. The way you use set in this case would prevent from adding another list `[1,2,1]`.

If you want to create a set like `[1,2]` then you can cast `studentList.num as Set`.

```groovy
def studentList = [[name:'test',grade:1,num:1],[name:'test1',grade:2,num:2],[name:'test',grade:1,num:1]]

def studentNums = studentList.num as Set

assert studentNums == [1,2] as Set
```

Comment: @ Szymon - We can use this for static values assert studentArray == [1,2].What about dynamic values?

Comment: The last line `assert studentArray == [1,2] as Set` is only added in the example for a documentation reason (to explain what is the current value of `studentArray`). You don't add this kind of assertions to your "production" code - you use them in the unit tests instead. Think about the above example as a unit test.